# Doxygen /// comments at end of line

Tags: objective-c, documentation, doxygen

When I'm commenting cvars I have a tendency to use the following format as I think it's easier to read.

```
UILabel *titleLabel; // The title label in the view
```

My current client uses doxygen and so I'm going back and converting my comments into doxygen format, which I hoped would be as simple as

```
UILabel *titleLabel; /// The title label in the view
```

Unfortunately this results in the comment being attached to the next cvar.

Is there any way of telling doxygen that single line comments should belong to the cvar on the line they are on ?

Comment: Allegedly yes, but I've never been able to make it work.  I'd be as interested in the answer to this one as you.

Comment: Doxygen has got a pretty decent user manual, both online and offline. If you want to use Doxygen, you should read at least some parts of it, like 'how do I put inline documentation' http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/docblocks.html.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are missing a `<`, try using:

```
UILabel *titleLabel; ///< The title label in the view
```

See the [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#memberdoc) for more information.

Comment: Thank you ! That's going to save me loads of time.

Comment: On Visual Studio, on mouse rollover, it produces an error: "No valid XML comment, it contains a space"